# What is the difference between 不 and 没?

Tags: meaning, usage, dictionary

I know 不 is the negative prefix for a verb, such as 不是. However 没 is also a negative prefix, such as 没有, so what is the difference between 不 and 没?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [Why is 有 (yǒu) the only verb that requires 没 while other verbs can use 不?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/247/why-is-%e6%9c%89-y%c7%92u-the-only-verb-that-requires-%e6%b2%a1-while-other-verbs-can-use-%e4%b8%8d) which is much more about etymology (and fairly advanced), and doesn't cover adjectives, e.g. 不好.  The best answer on the network seems to be [Tang Ho's](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/30001/8099), so I'll redirect the duplicate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

不 is the negative prefix for a verb and adjective, here are some examples:
不对,not right;
不好，not good;
不错，not bad;
你想去购物吗?不去.Do you want to go shopping? No,I don't;

However 没 is focused on existence or ownership, for example:
没有，I don't have it.
从没发生过，This never happens before.
这里没有人, No one is here.
我没钱, I don't have money.

I hope you are clear now!