# When do we use 没(mei3) and 不(bu4) before verbs in sentences?

Tags: word, verbs, negation

I have read some articles Chinese, my question is about above subject, because if I want to say:

```
我没喝 (it is wrong)
我不喝 (it is right)
```

are there list of verb can be followed by 没(mei3) and 不(bu4)?

Comment: Not an answer, but I wanted to point out that 没 is actually mei2, not mei3.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [Why is 有 (yǒu) the only verb that requires 没 while other verbs can use 不?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/247/why-is-%e6%9c%89-y%c7%92u-the-only-verb-that-requires-%e6%b2%a1-while-other-verbs-can-use-%e4%b8%8d) which is much more about etymology (and fairly advanced).

Answer (score 3):

没 and 不 are fundamentally different.

没 means "didn't"

不 means "won't" or "don't"

Actually your two sentences are perfectly normal Chinese sentences:

我没喝 means I didn't drink (it) -or- I haven't drank

我不喝 means I don't want to drink -or- I won't drink

**A Chinese English Dictionary**

**没**

> ADVERB INFORMAL
>   have not or did not
>
> 他来没来？——还没来呢。
>
> Tā lái méi lái？ —— hái méi lái ne.
>
> Has he come yet?--Not yet.

**不**

> 1 (used before verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs; never before 有) not; won't; not want to
>
> 我不去。
>
> Wǒ bù qù.
>
> I'm not going. or I won't go.
>
> 他昨天不来,可是今天来了。
>
> Tā zuótiān bù lái, kěshì jīntiān lái le.
>
> He didn't want to come yesterday,but he came today.

So the deal is: do you want to say haven't (yet), didn't (yet) = 没 -or- won't, don't (want to) = 不. Pretty much any verb can follow 没 and 不 everything just depends on what you want to express.

有 might be the only exception I can think of at the moment but that's been covered here:
[Why is 有 (yǒu) the only verb that requires 没 while other verbs can use 不?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/247/why-is-%E6%9C%89-y%C7%92u-the-only-verb-that-requires-%E6%B2%A1-while-other-verbs-can-use-%E4%B8%8D)

Comment: For 有 please take a look here: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/247/why-is-有-yǒu-the-only-verb-that-requires-没-while-other-verbs-can-use-不